# Showing words in a text file via textbox?

Tags: c#, file-io

My code simply reads the file, splits it into words and whows each word in the textbox with 0.1 seconds frequency.

I click to `"button1"` to get the file and split.

After I click `Start_Button` the program gets stuck. I can't see any problem in the code. Can anyone see it please?

My code is here;

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string text1, WordToShow;
        string[] WordsOfFile;
        bool LoopCheck;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {           
            OpenFileDialog BrowseFile1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            BrowseFile1.Title = "Select a text file";
            BrowseFile1.Filter = "Text File |*.txt";
            BrowseFile1.FilterIndex = 1;
            string ContainingFolder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            BrowseFile1.InitialDirectory = @ContainingFolder;
            //BrowseFile1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
            BrowseFile1.RestoreDirectory = true;
            if (BrowseFile1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                text1 = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(BrowseFile1.FileName);
                WordsOfFile = text1.Split(' ');
                textBox1.Text = text1;
            }
        }

        private void Start_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Interval = 100;
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            timer1.Start();
            LoopCheck = true;
            try
            {
                while (LoopCheck)
                {
                    foreach (string word in WordsOfFile)
                    {
                        WordToShow = word;
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                Form2 ErrorPopup = new Form2();
                if (ErrorPopup.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    ErrorPopup.Dispose();
                }
            }

        }

        private void Stop_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoopCheck = false;
            timer1.Stop();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = WordToShow;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of   `Thread.Sleep(1000);` use `async/await` feature with `Task.Delay` in order to keep your `UI` responsible:

```
private async void Start_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Interval = 100;
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        timer1.Start();
        LoopCheck = true;
        try
        {
            while (LoopCheck)
            {
                foreach (string word in WordsOfFile)
                {
                    WordToShow = word;
                    await Task.Delay(1000);
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Form2 ErrorPopup = new Form2();
            if (ErrorPopup.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                ErrorPopup.Dispose();
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: This solved the problem. Thank you. But I don't understand why there is a Thread.Sleep() method when we have more reliable one like this?